# Clock skew and Modification time in future issue in Qt App building

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt and start working on an app but get following *error while building project for real device.* Also on simulator app runs all the way fine it only gives error while building/running for real devices.
*Also it does not create any sis package in project folder directory.* Please help me out on it.

bq. make[1]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\tools\make.exe: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
The process "C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\tools\make.exe" exited normally.
Error while building project umrahqml (target: Symbian Device)
When executing build step 'Make'

*The error is all about clock skew problem and modification time issue. Any idea?*
My app is almost done but could not test as could not create sis package because of above error.

Any idea/help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your computer clock is set to the correct date/time.

Comment: Then the files you are trying to build have wrong (read: future) timestamps.

Comment: so what is solution??can u help?